# How to publish a FB notification from a FB connect app?

Tags: facebook

How can I publish a notification from a FB connect APP using only FMBL?
Is it possible?

Comment: Might be helpful to describe what you have already found about this topic, what specifically you are trying to do, or post code that you're currently working on!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with just fbml.  For one, you somehow need to specify *which* friends would receive notifications, meaning some kind of logic is necessary.

You need to call the REST API, either using JS on the client side:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/JS_API_M_FB.ApiClient.Notifications_send

or using xml on the back end:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Notifications.send

There are api client libraries for the most common web languages (python/php/ruby).